# Указание требуемых типов данных при передаче параметров

Tags: python, python-3.x

Класс векторов в двумерном пространстве:

```
class Vector:

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы тип данных передаваемых x и y мог быть только int? Или единственный вариант - проверять тип х и у в функции инициализации?:

```
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if type(self.x) != int or type(self.y) != int:
            raise SomeException('some error text')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, в любом случае такую проверку где-то писать придётся. Если такое надо проверять только в одном методе - то проще написать так, как в вашем примере, и не заморачиваться. Если одну и ту же проверку надо делать в нескольких методах - то можно вынести её в декоратор:

```
def check_args(method):
    def wrapped(self, x, y):
        if type(x) != int or type(y) != int:
            raise SomeException('some error text')
        return method(self, x, y)
    return wrapped


class Vector:

    @check_args
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать аннотации и установить библиотечку typeguard

```
from typeguard import typechecked

class Vector:

    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Можно, опять-таки с аннотациями, просто запускать программу через [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)